# Check if remote port is reachable using Centos

Tags: centos, netcat

On Dubian, I can do the following using `netcat` (aka `nc`, `ncat`):

```
michael@pi1:~ $ nc -zv 10.120.11.1 20 21 22 23 24
nc: connect to 10.120.11.1 port 20 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
Connection to 10.120.11.1 21 port [tcp/ftp] succeeded!
Connection to 10.120.11.1 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
Connection to 10.120.11.1 23 port [tcp/telnet] succeeded!
nc: connect to 10.120.11.1 port 24 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
michael@pi1:~ $
```

man nc on Dubian shows the following:

```
 -z      Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without sending any data to them.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l option.
```

On Centos7, I didn't originally have nc, so added using `sudo yum install nmap-ncat.x86_64`.

But, the `-z` flag is not supported.

```
[michael@box1 ~]$ nc -zv 10.255.255.1 22
nc: invalid option -- 'z'
Ncat: Try `--help' or man(1) ncat for more information, usage options and help. QUITTING.
[michael@box1 ~]$
```

Comment: You also could use `nmap 10.120.11.1 -p 20,21,22,23,24`.

Comment: @Thomas  Thanks Thomas.  Yes, seems to be a bit of a duplicate, but no really good answers.    `nmap` didn't seem to work.  Replies with `nmap 10.120.11.1 -p 22
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2017-07-29 14:29 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.03 seconds`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, I found that out as well that nc didn't support -z. I wonder why they dropped it. You could install an older version of ncat, or just use nmap.

Nmap
`nmap -sT -p <port>`

Comment: Thanks, `nmap remote.com -Pn -sT -p 20,21,22,23,24` seems to work.